# How to use if else condition in base adapter class

Tags: java, android

is there any way to use in my adapter class.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;

    if(!flag){
        ////
    }
    // Here i want to set if else condition but i am not able to do this.*/
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html Section `The if-then-else Statement`

Comment: Why would you apply any condition directly in class not in any method ?

Comment: I know how to use if else condition but when you will extends BaseAdapter class then you can not use as simple way which is we can use everywhere.@ThomasBouron

Comment: Constructor is the nice place to do that...

Comment: Can you simply write the logic that what you want to do with the help of if else condition..???

Comment: I have tried it but it's gives errors.@RushabhPatel

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if-else` syntax only in methods or constructors. I assume you want to initialize fields of `ImageAdapter` looking at some parameters. If so, you can do it at the constructor:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    private Context mContext;
    public String myField;


    public ImageAdapter(int mGalleryItemBackground, Context mContext, boolean flag) {
        this.mGalleryItemBackground = mGalleryItemBackground;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        if(!flag){
            myField = "abc";
        } else {
            myField = "cba";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is right but i want to use if else out side the function.

Comment: @SourabhTech you can't do that. Why do you need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following code.

```
String field = flag?"success":"fail";
```